# Permissions seem right, are wrong

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions

Here's what the permissions are on my directories:

```
$ls -l     
drwxrwx--- 5 jmartino   Discovery    60 Aug 12  2009 EmailDeDupe
drw-rw---- 2 kkonathala Discovery 16384 Aug 13 18:22 ListMatching
drwxrwx--- 2 jmartino   Discovery    43 Oct 18  2011 Max
```

But when I try to `cd` into ListMatching as kkonathala, I get:

```
$cd ListMatching/
-sh: cd: ListMatching/: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set the `x` (execute bit) in order to `cd` into a directory, i.e. do a `chmod +x` on your directory and all will be ok :)